# Is $\int^0_0 x^{-1} dx$ defined?

Tags: definite-integrals

Is an object like $$\int^0_0 x^{-1} dx$$ defined?

---

Context: when considering functions such as

$$f(x)=\int^{x^2}_xt^{-1}dt$$

would it therefore be necessary to give a piecewise definition of $f$ if we wished to include $0$ in the domain?

---

A little bit of random speculation, but if the object is supposedly defined to be $0$, then we would be allowed to write something like

$$\int^0_0\sqrt{\text{banana}}\quad d(\text{apple})=0$$

???

Comment: If I'm not wrong, that this $f$ is not defined for any $x$ right?

Comment: Nice question! For me $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}t^{-1}dt$ is not a function, but someone else can say that it's a function with domain $dom(f)=\{0\}$ and image $Im(f)=\{0\}$.

Comment: I assume it depends on your definition. Some would say $\int_a^a f\,dx \equiv 0$ which would be valid, whereas if you leave it more general $\int_a^b f\,dx \equiv F(b)-F(a)$ and consider $a=b$, then $F(b)-F(a)$ is not well-defined. Just a thought tho!

Comment: @yanko I put a better example

Comment: hmm, maybe you want to integrate from $x^2$ to $x$ because when $x$ is close to $0$ then $x^2<x$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_many_angels_can_dance_on_the_head_of_a_pin%3F

Comment: you can consider the limit at 0, by the fundamental theorem this limit is equal to the limit of $log(x)-log(x^2)=-log(x)$ which is infinity

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Thanks - just what I was looking for! This should be closed then

Comment: Hm.. so there are some definitions which define it to be $0$. But then this allows for ridiculous examples such as the one I've put below?

Comment: Perhaps more ridiculously, we can have integrals such as $\int_{-1}^1\frac1x~\mathrm dx$, though this is a much different matter.

Comment: The function in the integral can perfectly be undefined in a set of measure zero. $\int_{0}^{0}f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\chi_{\{0\}}dx$ is zero for every function $f$, even if not defined at $0$.